# Magento add grouped product to cart as a single item

Tags: magento

I want to know if it's possible to change how the Grouped Product works in Magento. Instead of adding the multiple products in the cart seperately when adding the grouped product to cart, I want to add THE grouped product (which means only one product) to the cart, just like a Packaged Product.

I could use the Packaged Product in this case, however I don't want the user to see the different products available as an option and using the latter would be too much of a hassle.

Is there a way to change this and where can I do modify the necessary files ?

Thanks you !

Answer (score 0):

Magento doesn't have any notion of "packaged products" out of the box. Do you mean bundle products? That's conceptually what you want if you want multiple SKUs added to cart with a single action. If you don't want to present the customer with options about the child products, just set them to be included by default and then override the template and/or CSS not to display the option interface.